# Append an img to closest div

Tags: jquery, append, closest, appendto, alt

I've been scouring the web for hours trying to find a solution to this that works for me but I just can't seem to find one.

I need an image (`[alt="post-banner"]`) to be moved into #blog-banner-container. The problem is, all the images with that alt get moved into the first div. I'm presuming I have to use `.closest()` but I don't know how to use it.

**jQuery**

```
$('[alt="post-banner"]').appendTo('#blog-banner-container');
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I notice you have three `div` elements with the same id `blog-banner-container`. Was this intentional? This will cause undesired effects.

Comment: @Shaun Because this is for a RapidWeaver theme, I don't have the power to edit the divs, and I even had to use `.prepend()` to get the `#blog-banner-container` to appear

Answer (score 0):

You can select the parent, then the sibling at the level with the ID you are looking for.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewlively/DNAEB/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="blog-entry">
        <div id="blog-banner-container"></div>
        <div class="blog-entry-title">Title</div>
        <div class="blog-entry-body">
            <img src="#" alt="post-banner" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('[alt="post-banner"]').each(function() {
    $(this).parents().siblings('#blog-banner-container').append(this);
});
```